# Dimension of Matrix in MIMO with multi-path

Tags: digital-communications, mimo

In a MIMO system, the received signal is supposed to be $y = Hx + n$, where $H$ is the channel of dimension $N_t \times N_r$, $x$ is the transmitted signal with dimension of $N_t\times 1$ , and $n$ is the noise, finally the resulted signal $y$ represents the received signal of dimension of $N_r\times1$.

Assuming that I need to use channel $H$ as multi-path channel whose number of taps is $e.g.$ 5 .. The question is:

- Will the dimension of channel $H$ will be $5N_t\times N_r$?
- If so, how can we perform the matrix multiplication of $Hx$ in  $y = Hx + n$, so the received signal $y$ will be of dimension $5N_r\times1$?

Comment: I think you've been writing MIMO code for more than four months now – why haven't you gone ahead and just tried?

Comment: Also, removed the tag [tag:matlab] because – this is not a matlab question, but a question on how to generally model a multipath MIMO channel.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ,, I worked on that for more than four years or months, That's not the question.  thnx for below answer, I'll try to check it

Comment: I don't understand your comment – can you elaborate? I always found it highly insightful to just sit down and *test* my approaches with code! That's why I recommended that. The comment that you've been working on this for quite some time was meant to encourage you – I was assuming that simply simulating the above equation $y=Hx+n$ would be trivial to you, so that trying out comes at low cost to you. You go wild with matlab :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: if you transmit one block of $N$ symbols (no data before it for at least $L$ symbol times) over a frequency-selective channel of length $L$, then the channel matrix will be of dimension $NN_TN_R\times N$.

The long answer: start with $N_T=N_R=1$. Then the $n^{\text{th}}$ received sample can be written as

$$y_n=\sum_{l=0}^Lh_lx_{n-l}+z_n$$

If you arrange these samples in a vector-matrix form you get

$$\mathbf{y}_{N\times 1}=\mathbf{H}_{N\times N}\mathbf{x}_{N\times 1} + \mathbf{z}_{N\times 1}$$

Now let $N_T=1$ while the number of receive antennas $N_R$, then the $n^{\text{th}}$ received sample over $m^{\text{th}}$ receive antenna is

$$y_n^{(m)}=\sum_{l=0}^Lh_l^{(m)}x_{n-l}+z^{(m)}_n$$

for $m=1,\,2,\,\ldots,\,N_R$. If you arrange these sample in a vector-Matrix form, you get

$$\mathbf{y}_{NN_R\times 1}=\mathbf{H}_{NN_R\times N}\mathbf{x}_{N\times 1} + \mathbf{z}_{NN_R\times 1}$$

Similarly, you can do the general case for $N_T$ transmit and $N_R$ receive antennas.

As you can see, to make this work on block-by-block basis, you need to padding $L$ zeros before each block to eliminate the inter-block interference. Alternatively, you can use cyclic-prefixed (CP)-OFDM, which is more efficient at the receiver side.

Answer (score -1):

> Will the dimension of channel $H$ will be $5N_t$x$N_r$ ?? If so, How can we perform the matrix multiplication of $Hx$ in  $y = Hx + n$ ? ... So the received signal $y$ will be of dimension $5N_r$x1, right?

No!

$\mathbf H$ is defined to work as following: With $\mathbf x$ being the transmit vector, and $\mathbf y$ being the receive vector, and in the absence of noise, it is

$$\mathbf y = \mathbf H\mathbf x\text.$$

Thus, since the dimensions of $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ are fixed (at $N_r$ and $N_t$, respectively), the only choice for the dimension of $\mathbf H$ is $N_t\times N_r$.

A multipath channel can't be represented with a simple construct such as 2D Matrix. So, **channel Matrix** and **multipath** will **not work together** unless you redefine $\mathbf x$ and probably also $\mathbf y$.

I like your idea of "inflating" the transmit vector i.e. you could argue that individual delay slots are active orthogonally to each other and could restrict $\mathbf H$ to be causal. However, I'm personally not aware of anyone who's done that – so, finding a good provable notation that works out like the actual multipath MIMO channel would be worth giving it a shot. I'm pretty sure that the result won't be a simple $5N_t \times N_r$ Matrix, but probably be a tensor of higher dimensionality ($N_t \times N_r \times 5 \times 5$) to describe the convolution that happens between every path, but it'll be certainly interesting.

In short: You will need a more complicated system model.

In fact, describing and correcting multipath MIMO channels is so complicated that in practice *we don't*. Instead, modern communication systems that use MIMO (that being WiFi and LTE) use techniques like OFDM to split the wideband multipath MIMO channel in many narrowband single-path MIMO channels and then deal with these individually, because these single-path MIMO channels are the MIMO channels we know how do deal with using the well-established "boring" math.